# An SMTP To address is required to send a message. Set the message smtp_envelope_to, to, cc, or bcc address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, rspec

I have super simple mailer:

```
class Mailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def welcome_email(email)
    @email = email
    mail to: email, subject: "[#{I18n.t 'email_subject_welcome'}"
  end
end
```

but when I run tests with `example@gmail.com` I get this error:

`An SMTP To address is required to send a message. Set the message smtp_envelope_to, to, cc, or bcc address.`

[image: Email is present]

What should be done here?

Comment: this error usually comes up when you have to: email nil or empty.. anyway, you need to check if your email variable is not nil and actually an email.

Comment: Updated with screenshot showing that email is present

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem occurred because of interceptor:

```
class SandboxEmailInterceptor
  def self.delivering_email(message)
    message.to = Rails.application.secrets.your_email
  end
end

ActionMailer::Base.register_interceptor(SandboxEmailInterceptor) unless Rails.env.production?
```

Where `secrets.yml` has `your_email: <%= ENV["YOUR_EMAIL"] %>`, and my `application.yml` whith email was missing.

Answer (score 1):

How are you actually calling it in Rspec?  post that code if you haven't figured it out yet.  It sounds to me like the variable email is nil.

Comment: I'm calling ServiceObject which actually calls Sidekiq and then Mailer is invoked. As shown in example above, email address is not nil.